# Problem Loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

file name: ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso.
currently windows 8.1 installed on my laptop.
I am trying to install ubuntu from usb flash drive and created a bootable usb using rufus. When I boot from usb it gave me four options.
[try ubuntu, install ubuntu, oem install and check disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iLep.jpg)

when I select the option 1 (try ubuntu) or option 2 (install ubuntu)
then it gives me an error message saying

> `18.206119 Problem Loading UEFI:db X.509 certificate (-65)`

[image]

Comment: It is probable that it is related to **secure boot**. When you restart your PC, enter to BIOS options then disable secure boot and see if the error still exists.

Comment: @singrium, it is related to secure boot. Do you have any suggestion on how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena You can disable that from the BIOS menu.

Comment: @singrium, I have secure boot disabled and still have the issue, I have posted my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354493/ubuntu-dual-boot-fails-with-loading-uefidb-x-509-certificate-65-error)

Answer (score 0):

I've had the exact same error message while trying to install Lubuntu. I solved it by changing the BIOS boot setting to a setting that was not UEFI ; CSM in my case. My laptop is a Toshiba C855D-S5303. Am AMD Dual-core 300E. Although I still recieved an error message about "no IRQ handler" Lubuntu would install.